# JavaFX abstract controller inheritance didn't work

Tags: javafx

I have a big problem while coding my application.
Well, I try to extend my ReaderController class, which is abstract and it is set as controller in my fxml file.

There is my code:

```
public abstract class ReaderController extends AnchorPane{
@FXML
TextField id;
@FXML
 TextField name;
@FXML
TextField surname;
@FXML
 TextField PESEL;
@FXML
TextField dateOfBirth;
@FXML
TextField documentType;
@FXML
TextField documentNumber;
@FXML
TextField email;
@FXML
TextField phoneNumber;
@FXML
TextField street;
@FXML
TextField city;
@FXML
Button addReader;

Parent root;
public ReaderController()
{

}
```

And there is my subclass:

```
public class EditReaderController extends ReaderController{

public EditReaderController() throws IOException 
{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/AddUser.fxml"));
    root= (Parent) loader.load();
    loader.setController(this);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Edit User");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}
public void initialize(){
    addReader.setText("Edit!");
    id.setText(String.valueOf(SQLController.getInstance().getLastIndexOfReader()));
}
```

I have an error:

```
aused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
... 75 more
```

So how can I extend my abstract controller into my EditReaderController ?

**UPD 1** my fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.library.controllers.ReaderController">
   <children>
      <HBox layoutX="151.0" layoutY="64.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="129.0">
               <children>
                  <GridPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="129.0">
                     <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                     </columnConstraints>
                     <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                     </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Nr czytelnika" />
                        <Label text="Imię" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="Nazwisko" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="PESEL" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Label text="Data urodzenia" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="15.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </GridPane>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="178.0">
               <children>
                  <GridPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="178.0">
                     <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                     </columnConstraints>
                     <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                     </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="id" editable="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="34.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="name" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets right="25.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                        <TextField fx:id="surname" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets right="25.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                        <TextField fx:id="PESEL" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets right="25.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                        <TextField fx:id="dateOfBirth" editable="false" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets right="25.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="15.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </GridPane>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <GridPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="99.0">
                     <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                     </columnConstraints>
                     <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                     </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Typ dokumentu" />
                        <Label text="Nr dokumentu" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="E-mail" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="Nr telefonu" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Label text="Ulica" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                        <Label text="Miasto" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="15.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </GridPane>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="195.0">
               <children>
                  <GridPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="195.0">
                     <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                     </columnConstraints>
                     <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                     </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="documentType">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets right="25.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                        <TextField fx:id="documentNumber" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets right="25.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                        <TextField fx:id="email" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets right="25.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                        <TextField fx:id="phoneNumber" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets right="25.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                        <TextField fx:id="street" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets right="25.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                        <TextField fx:id="city" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets right="25.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="15.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </GridPane>
                  <Button fx:id="addReader" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onAddReaderAction" text="Dodaj" textAlignment="CENTER">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="100.0" top="25.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you share your FXML file?

Comment: Here you go, i updated my post.

Comment: It is probably because your `ReaderController` class is abstract, do you really need that class to be abstract?

Comment: I have 3 subclasses like EditReaderController. I think I need abstract class, because i don't want to build 3 new fxml files only for edit one field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using an abstract class in your fxml?

Look at this line:

```
fx:controller="com.library.controllers.ReaderController"
```

You have a non-abstract subclass. Why not use it?

```
fx:controller="com.library.controllers.EditReaderController"
```

Or use your own non-abstract class.

I didn't see any abstract members in `ReaderController`.
Removing the `abstract` modifier may also solve this.

Also, it's really confusing that your controller class is extending `AnchorPane`..

Also, according to @sillyfly in the comments,

> there really isn't much use calling setController after the call to FXMLLoader#load, as by this point the fields have been injected... I think it would even raise an exception about the controller already being set...

According to the comment,

> I know it, but i didn't know, how to set a new Controller through action ( for example clicked Edit or Add button)

You should first read https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/button.htm to know how to run some code when a button is clicked, and run

```
loader.setController(your new controller);
```

when your button is clicked, and remove the `fx:controller` field, because you already set the controller in your logic code.

Comment: I would add to this answer that there really isn't much use calling `setController` _after_ the call to `FXMLLoader#load`, as by this point the fields have been injected... I think it would even raise an exception about the controller already being set...

Comment: I have 3 subclasses like EditReaderController. I think I need abstract class, because i don't want to build 3 new fxml files only for edit one field.

Comment: So why do you set the `fx:controller` as an abstract class? Don't you know abstract classes cannot be instantiated directly?

Comment: I know it, but i didn't know, how to set a new Controller through action ( for example clicked Edit or Add button).